# Neural Network Hidden layer has same number of units?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I've never thought deeply before but one question came out of my mind
I realized that I and others commonly use each hidden layer that has the same number of units.
Like if I have 2 hidden layers with each has 100 activation units.

I remember that in Prof. Andrew Ng's lecture he also mentioned that make sure the number of units for each layer to be same. Why is that so?
I never thought it was questionable, I just used it without any doubt.

Can anyone explain it with easy word?

Comment: I don't think this is so. In fact, in some of Andrew Ng's examples each hidden layer has different # of hidden units. Look at the examples where he emphasizes getting the dimensions right, he has a few examples there.

Comment: He mentioned in his lecture that make sure that the # of units in hidden layers should be same.
That is why I am asking. if Hidden layer 1 has 100 units then hidden layer 2 has 100 units... if Hidden layer 1 has 50 units then hidden layer 2 has 50 units and so on.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the video or citation?

Comment: Go to Coursera, find Andrew Ng's Machine Learning class then week 5 at 'Putting it together' mentions several times that the number of units in hidden layer should be same.
https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/Wh6s3/putting-it-together
Besides that, I can't find now but what I remember also is that he clearly mention that 'be sure the number of units in hidden layer is same to the other hidden layers'.

Comment: You are correct and he did say that and someone actually asked me the same question that why is it so and I landed in your question here. Did you find a reason? Coz in my opinion and experience, there is no such rule like this.